# AngularJS - updating the model shared by different controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm just starting with AngularJS, building my first test web app.
I have several controllers that share the same model.

This is my model:

```
uxctModule.factory ("ModelData", function () {
   var data = {
        param1: '', 
        param2: '',
        param3: '',
        [more params....]
   }
   return data
});
```

So this is an example of my controller

```
uxctModule.controller ('PageOne', function ($scope, ModelData){
    $scope.data = ModelData;
    [do things here]
});
```

I'm now trying to change the model by loading a string from a file, and I was expecting the app to update accordingly.
So in a controller I'm loading a file and trying to update the model:

```
uxctModule.controller ('NavigationController', function ($scope, ModelData) {
     $scope.data = ModelData;
     $scope.browsePressed = function (evt) {

        var f = evt.target.files[0]; 
        if (f) {
            var r = new FileReader();
            r.onload = function(e) { 
                var contents = e.target.result;
                console.log (contents);
                console.log ("ModelData was " + ModelData.param1);
                ModelData = JSON.parse(contents);
                console.log ("ModelData is now " + ModelData.param1);
            }

            r.readAsText(f);
        }
        else { 
            alert("Failed to load file");
        }
     }
});
```

I've built a "debugger" div in the html to see the model:

```
<div id="debuggerBox" ng-controller="Debugger" width='300'>
        <pre>{{data | json}}</pre>
    </div>
```

...whose controller is simply:

```
    uxctModule.controller ('Debugger', function ($scope, ModelData){
    $scope.data = ModelData;
});
```

Now, when changing the model content loading the external file I can see on the console the right logs (values changed), but on the debugger box the Model object is still holding the old values.
As I said, I'm an AngularJS beginner, so maybe I'm doing something really wrong here. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're replacing the **whole object**:

```
ModelData = JSON.parse(contents);
```

with this, the `ModelData` references another object but the original object **is not modified**.

You could fix this by copying field by field to the `ModelData`. Sample code:

```
var tempModelData = JSON.parse(contents);
ModelData.param1 = tempModelData.param1;
```

or you could try [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy):

```
angular.copy(JSON.parse(contents), ModelData);
```

Also try [$scope.$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply) to let angular aware of the changes:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
       angular.copy(JSON.parse(contents), ModelData);
});
```

Comment: while your explanation makes lot of sense - shame on me - it still doesn't work. I've tried both ways, and the debugger div is still showing me old values